# IBM Worklight - What is the purpose of "Provide Library Resource"?

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Someone can explain what does the following do?

I want to deploy a Worklight-based Dojo Android app, but the exported .apk shows scriptError:21 messages when the local WiFi isn't enabled.

I already copied all necessary files from the toolkit to my www-folder.

=> I even made a script to be sure i have all the needed files in the right structure:

set src_folder= dojo-toolkit folder

set dst_folder= project WWW-folder

*FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (providedLibRes.txt) DO XCOPY "%src_folder%\%%a" "%dst_folder%\%%a" /i /z /y /s*

[image]

**So the problem is:**
there are no dojo resource call's as i can see from this console but when the flag is unchecked nothing works... (and the javascript console is asking for files in the default folder...)

Comment: It would be better if you also mention in your question the complete scriptError:21 that you are getting, and where you are getting it (preview? device? which device?), as well as your Worklight version.

Comment: see more details on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859321/worklight-project-searches-for-main-js-and-typematic-js-when-provide-library-re

Comment: Great. A duplicate. :)

Comment: It's the same problem... 
with the flag on, there are no dojo library requests shown and everything works.
without the flag, there are no dojo library requests shown and nothing works.
So the question was clear in my eye's... What does the flag do...

Comment: My reply here explains what the flag does - if you are missing files, the server will provide them in runtime; Please refer to the link in the answer about similar questions, one of which will likely shed more light.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of articles explaining in great detail how to work with Dojo in Worklight, as well as the use of "Provide Library Resources":

- [Blog post: The Dojo Library in Worklight Studio V6.0](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/the_dojo_library_in_worklight_studio_v6_0?lang=en)
- [IBM Worklight Information Center: Worklight Dojo library project setup](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.worklight.doc/topics/cdojolibprjsetupwl.html)

Basically, when the application is missing some Dojo-related resources, and this option is **ticked**, then you will see in this console all the requests for resources that are missing and that are instead being provided by Worklight Studio.

This lets you know what to fix in your project; after that, and when moving to production, you can and should turn it off - this option is available only from Worklight Studio, so if you close Eclipse, or are not in the same network, it will fail.

Next, you mention scriptError:21, and this has various reasons. You need to make sure you are using the very latest release of Worklight (6.0.0.1 fixpack 1, build number is 20130926), where such issues are resolved.

Also see related questions about scriptError:21 in Worklight:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D+scripterror%3A21+is%3Aquestion

Comment: you have an other clue than the infocenter doc's?
We are trying to launch the app but it is not working...

Comment: In my testing with the Developer Edition (6.0.0.1 fixpack 1), available from the Eclipse Marketplace, I could create a new Worklight project and application with the built-in Dojo framework, add the Android environment, build and deploy and preview in the Worklight Console's MBS w/out any errors. Also please note that this question was about "what is Request Library Resources", not about a failing project per se - that is covered in your team member's other question. Let us please use only 1 question. If this question is covered, please mark as answered. Thanks.

Comment: I still do not have an answer on the functionality of the flag.
=> you say when it is ticked i see all the resources that i need to copy into my www-folder. I say that is not what it does. 
So i can keep asking the same question.. 
When I un-tick the flag, why do i get errors on resources i never request when the flag is ticked?

Comment: Did you read the two official links I have mentioned in my answer, which talk about how to use Dojo in Worklight as well as explain this console? If the option is not ticked, you will get errors about resources that you are not providing in your project; when it is ticked, they are provided for you.

Comment: Something else is wrong in your setup; as I mentioned, in a clean new project it is working. If you want any further help, export your project from eclipse and provide a download link. Thanks.

Comment: I already had read them, so i know. That is why i ask a question on stackoverflow because the intel in the documents is wrong and i need a workaround... (so i'm open for creative ideas)

Comment: how can i give you access on our bitbucketgit? @Idan-Adar

Comment: I don't know, never used it. Is it invite-based? Can you not simply export the Worklight project, zip it and email to: iadar at il dot ibm.com?