# Worklight project searches for main.js and typematic.js when 'provide library resources' is disabled

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight version v6.0.0.20130917-1749,
Dojo 1.9

When I run the preview of an android project when 'provide library resources' is disabled I get the following errors:

```
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://10.99.8.72:10080/Klappr/apps/services/preview/Klappr/android/1.0/default/main.js"
    main.js
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://10.99.8.72:10080/Klappr/apps/services/preview/Klappr/android/1.0/default/typematic.js"
    typematic.js
```

In android this results in a 'scriptError:21'.

I copied all necessary files from the toolkit to my www-folder.
[image]

main.js and typematic.js are never required in my js-files.
I don't know why it still searches for it, and not in my www/dojo folder, but instead in the android/1.0/default folder.

---

Here you see that typematic.js is included. Still I get the error.

[image]

---

I updated Worklight to 6.0.0.1 fix, and still get the error.

Comment: Please always mention what is your Worklight version. Did you manually rename your JS to "main.js"? This file exists by default in any Worklight project, but only starting Worklight 6.1.0, not yet available.

Comment: You also mention that you copied all files - are you sure you've copied them to the correct locations, perhaps this matters. Could be that the files are being incorrectly referenced.

Comment: @IdanAdar I mentioned my Worklight version

Comment: @IdanAdar I didn't manually rename my js to main.js, it was the name of the project I think

Comment: Can you be a bit more certain, please? Also, which "v6"? build number? Is this a brand new app with Dojo with no alterations?

Comment: @IdanAdar Worklight version v6.0.0.20130917-1749, Dojo 1.9

Comment: @IdanAdar I am certain the main js file was the name of the project, I made a new project and it was also called the name of the project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40821/discussion-between-ken-vernaillen-and-idan-adar)

Comment: @IdanAdar

When I run another project, the same thing happens, but with 2 other files. 

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://10.99.8.72:10080/BoilerplateViews/apps/services/preview/TestApp/android/1.0/default/dojox/mobile/FormLayout.js"
FormLayout.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://10.99.8.72:10080/BoilerplateViews/apps/services/preview/TestApp/android/1.0/default/dojox/gesture/swipe.js"
swipe.js

Comment: Totally sounds like you are missing the files. Refer to my answer in the other question, it links to similar questions about scriptError:21

Comment: I think you need to explain what is "copied all necessary files", because I now created a new worklight project with dojo and android environment, and I do not get these errors with and without the checkbox ticked. It could be that this "copy" operation, was just done incorrectly, and you need to explain what you've done there.

Comment: I also suggest to use the latest Worklight version, which is 6.0.0.1 fixpack1, with build number 20130926 - this is available from both the Eclipse Marketplace as well as for customers in FixCentral.

Comment: @IdanAdar I updated my question with more info. Copying the necessary files, I mean the files that show up in the Dojo console. core-web-layer_nl.js and mobile-ui-layer_nl.js

Comment: Can you mention ALL of your steps, from creating the project to copying the files and folders, so that I could recreate it?

Comment: @IdanAdar Fred will give you the sourcecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Worklight project Fred emailed me I could see the mentioned errors as well.
I then:

1. Removed the "dojo" and "dijit" folders from the www folder
2. Re-added them from the dojoLib folder in the workspace
3. Re-built and deployed the application
4. Previewed via Worklight Console

The errors from before are gone and I could now pass the "splash image" and see the actual app. 
I do not think this is related to "Require Library Resources", but to ... something, else.

When looking at the dev tools console, there are now all sort of other errors, but I suspect those are due to dumping the entirety of the dojo and dijit folders into the www folder, and could use some optimization and fixing, but the actual hurdle mentioned in the question is lifted.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF9L4.png
[image]